# Create a many-many relationship from existing tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of sentences, and a table of words. I am trying to create an intermediate table so I can quickly look up what sentences contain a word.

```
Table A (sentences)
id INT PRIMARY KEY
sentence VARCHAR

Table B (words)
id INT PRIMARY KEY
word VARCHAR

Table C (relationship table)
id INT PRIMARY KEY
sentence_id INT
word_id INT
```

Can I *populate* Table C with SQL?

The query would go through the words in B(words) and for each word, record which sentences it is in from A(Sentences) by making entries in table C.

Many thanks, you SQL whizzes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with:

```
insert into table C (sentence_id, word_id)
values (
select A.sentence_id, B.word_id from table B, table A
where locate(word, sentence) > 0
order by word, sentence )
```

Comment: Does "locate" differentiate between a single word in a sentence AND also part of a word in a sentence. Is it similar to "LIKE" operator in Sql server?

Comment: interesting take.. i was playing around with a JOIN ON a.sentence LIKE CONCAT("%",b.word,"%") but this seems cleaner!

Comment: You may need a join or subselect.  I also played with this: `where locate(word, sentence) > 0 and word IN (select unique word from B as B2)`